# Make Custom operator with observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, operators

```
const apiData = ajax('/api/data').pipe(map((res: any) => {
if (!res.response) {
  console.log('Error occurred.');
  throw new Error('Value expected!');
}
return res.response;
}),
```

I need to wrap pipe function into a custom operator with observable.
Need to handle error and data validation into common API service.

Comment: Why are you using ajax and not the Angular built-in `HttpClient`?

Comment: there is just API call

Answer (score 1):

So what's the problem? You can wrap both the Observable and operator with a function.

```
const createObs = () => ajax('/api/data').pipe(
  map((res: any) => {
    if (!res.response) {
      console.log('Error occurred.');
      throw new Error('Value expected!');
    }
    return res.response;
  }),
);

createObs().pipe(/* whatever */).subscribe();
```

Comment: If I want to replace any with multiple interface then what should I do @Martin?

Comment: You can use generics https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html